# Jquery/JS and CSS Horizontal list Navigation Click Drop Down Hyperlinks Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created what seemed a pretty straight forward horizontal navigation menu with css and jquery drop down elements, but for some reason it doesn't seem follow links on the click down menu.

I have made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3GBE/19/

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-108">
      <a title="Sub" href="http://Media">Hover</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-109">
          <a title="Audio" href="http://Audio">Audio</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-110">
          <a href="http://Visual">Visual</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-112">
      <a href="http://Events">Navi</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-typemenu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-117">
      <a href="http://click">Click</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-115">
          <a href="http://HQ">Headquarters</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-116">
          <a href="http://Magazine">Magazine</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hover over "hover" is fine, and the "click" link works at it should, but the sub menu links don't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to `$('.menu-item-has-children>a')`, targeting only the anchor tag, and not the list item which contains the submenu as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3GBE/20/

Comment: It's better not to link your logic to HTML elements ( e.g. using `a`). Using classes decouples the presentation from the logic and allows you to use the same script for any structure such as `span` or `div` etc.

Comment: @Ramy I agree with that, however, there is no class on the target element, which is the anchor tag. The answer is specific to the given html.

Comment: Fair enough. A nice notice to the OP won't hurt anyone and will promote good practices as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your first jQuery snippet to :

```
$('.sub-menu a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The click on the links is propagating up and triggering the click event handler you have on the parent items.

Comment: I believe this is treating the symptom rather than the issue itself and adds one more listener that we can avoid.

Comment: @Ramy - I didn't add the click handler, the OP did. I just modified the line he had inside it.

Comment: @j08691 That's correct. I didn't mean that "you" added it. I just meant that we can avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-menu links are inside the element with class `.menu-has-children` so since you added `return false;` to the click event, the links are not clickable. You should add the event listener to the link not the element.

Notice that I added the class `menu-link` to the `a` element of the main menu. Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bh7Yz/3/)

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', '.menu-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parentMenu = $(this).parents('.menu-item-has-children');
    $parentMenu.toggleClass('active');
    $('.sub-menu', $parentMenu).toggleClass('visible');
});
```